# make query to table before run recorder.Migration (django_migrations)?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to write in table **django_migrations**  for that I am using:

*fix_migration.py*

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.migrations import recorder
    recorder.MigrationRecorder(connection).record_applied("registro_movimientos", "0001_initial")
```

I am applying that via  `python manage.py runscript fix_migration.py`

but I need check first if that migrations was applied before , some like that:

```
query = django_migrations.filter(name=0001_initial, app="registro_movimientos")

if not query:
    recorder.M ....
```

thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one solution

*first* : execute sql for searching dependency migration

*after* : execute sql for verify if the current migration was applied

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.migrations import recorder

cursor = connection.cursor()
depends = cursor.execute(
    'SELECT name FROM django_migrations WHERE name = "0001_initial" AND app = "registro_movimientos"')

re = cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM django_migrations WHERE name = "0002_auto_20171205_1645" AND app = "registro_movimientos"')


if depends and not re:
    print("applying migration 0002_auto_20171205_1645 ... ")
    recorder.MigrationRecorder(connection).record_applied("registro_movimientos", "0002_auto_20171205_1645")
```

works .